# Error Prometheus endpoint for checking AlertManager

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I installed Prometheus (follow in this link: https://devopscube.com/setup-prometheus-monitoring-on-kubernetes/)

But, when checking status of Targets, it shows "Down" for AlertManager service, every another endpoint are up, please see the attached file [image]

Then, I check Service Discovery, the discovered labels shows:

> "**address**="192.168.180.254:9093"
>   __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind="Pod"
>   __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name="alertmanager-6c666985cc-54rjm"
>   __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_node_name="worker-node1"
>   __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_protocol="TCP"
>   __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_ready="true"
>   __meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name="alertmanager"
>   __meta_kubernetes_namespace="monitoring"
>   __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_cni_projectcalico_org_podIP="192.168.180.254/32"
>   __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotationpresent_cni_projectcalico_org_podIP="true"
>   __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name="alertmanager"
>   __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name="alertmanager"
>   __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number="9093""

But Target Labels show another port (**8080**), I don't know why:

> ```
> instance="192.168.180.254:8080"
> job="kubernetes-service-endpoints"
> kubernetes_name="alertmanager"
> kubernetes_namespace="monitoring"
> ```

[image]

Comment: installation of Prometheus operator, like Iakovos Belonias advise was helpful? Do you still have this issue?

Comment: I am not successful with helm. I got another error when installing prometheus operator: manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
Error: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "prometheusrulemutate.monitoring.coreos.com": Post https://prometheus-prometheus-oper-operator.default.svc:443/admission-prometheusrules/mutate?timeout=29s: service "prometheus-prometheus-oper-operator" not found

Comment: It's because you have installed Helm 3 which do not support some hooks from previous version. Anyway It will install all objects.
Are you using Minikube, Kubeadm or On-Prem? I folowed this instruction and didnt get this error.

Comment: Does your env using any firewalls?

Comment: @PjoterS : I used kubeadm on prem, I think it is incompatibility with my kubernetes version. And I also use firewalld but followed to installation instruction of k8s

Comment: What exactly Kubeadm and K8s version? I want to reproduce it as much as possible and check.

Comment: @PjoterS: I installed 1.16.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to install prometheus and grafana without getting sick, you need to do it though helm.

[First install helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/)

And then

```sh
helm install installationWhatEverName stable/prometheus-operator
```

Comment: Yes, I will try this method.

Comment: I got another error when using helm: manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"
manifest_sorter.go:175: info: skipping unknown hook: "crd-install"

Error: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "prometheusrulemutate.monitoring.coreos.com": Post https://prometheus-prometheus-oper-operator.default.svc:443/admission-prometheusrules/mutate?timeout=29s: service "prometheus-prometheus-oper-operator" not found

Comment: @taibc unfortunately youare not the only the one experiencing this error https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/19452

Comment: @lakovos Yes, I think it is because of incompatibility between helm 3 and kubernetes. May be I need to downgrade my kubernetes version

Comment: I think you need to downgrade the helm not the Kubernetes cluster

Comment: @lakovos Belonias: I tried to downgrade Helm to 2.xx but still got the error

Comment: Final, I installed kubernetes 1.15.4 and helm 3 then it is successful

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced your issue on GCE.

If you are using version `1.16+` you have probably changed `apiVersion` as in tutorial you have `Deployment` in `extensions/v1beta1`. Since K8s `1.16+` you need to change it to `apiVersion: apps/v1`. Otherwise you will get error like:

```
error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Second thing, in 1.16+ you need to specify `selector`. If you will not do it you will receive another error:

```
`error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`
```

It would look like:

```
...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prometheus-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prometheus-server
    spec:
      containers:
...
```

Regarding port `8080` please check [this article](https://vitalflux.com/kubernetes-port-targetport-and-nodeport/) with example.

> **Port:** Port is the port number which makes a service visible to
>   other services running within the same K8s cluster.  In other words,
>   in case a service wants to invoke another service running within the
>   same Kubernetes cluster, it will be able to do so using port specified
>   against “port” in the service spec file.

It worked for my environment in GCE. Did you configure firewall for your endpoints?

In addition. In `Helm 3` some `hooks` were deprecated. You can find this information [here](https://github.com/datawire/ambassador/issues/2057#issuecomment-560007192).

If you still have issue please provide your YAMLs witch applied changes to version 1.16+.